# Riemannian metric in the real projective plane built from $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

We have $\mathbb{R}^3$, and then the quotient
$$\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2=\mathbb{R}^3/\sim$$
where $x\sim y$ if $\exists k\in\mathbb{R}^*$ such that $x=ky$.

I have the open sets $U_1,U_2,U_3$ where $U_i=\{[p_1,p_2,p_3]\mid p_i\neq 0\}$ and the charts:
$$\phi_i:U_i\to\mathbb{R}^2$$
given by 
$$\phi_1([p_1,p_2,p_3])=\left(\frac{p_2}{p_1},\frac{p_3}{p_1}\right)$$
$$\phi_2([p_1,p_2,p_3])=\left(\frac{p_1}{p_2},\frac{p_3}{p_2}\right)$$
$$\phi_3([p_1,p_2,p_3])=\left(\frac{p_1}{p_3},\frac{p_2}{p_3}\right)$$

so in this way we get a differentiable structure on it.

I want to know how, with this differentiable structure we can build a Riemannian metric on it. Would it be different from the metric induced by the first fundamental form of $S^2$ and the fact that the antipodal mapping is an isometry?

Comment: Until you tell me how you propose to define a Riemannian metric from the three charts, I can't tell you what your answer will be. Using the usual Riemannian metric on $\Bbb R^2$ on those three charts will not give you something that patches together compatibly. The usual way, as you point out, is to use the standard metric on $S^2$, which is invariant under the antipodal map and therefore descends without a problem to a metric on $\Bbb RP^2$.